# Can an application running on OpenShift be part of a load balancer setup with the same application running on legacy Linux/Tomcat

Tags: openshift, load-balancing

I am maintaining a couple of spring boot web applications.

They are currently running as WAR files deployed on the same Tomcat instance on two Linux servers.

In front I have a load balancer to distribute the load through url `myapps.mydomain.com`.

Apart from the actual applications, both backend Tomcat instances exposes `/up/up.html` to allow the load balancer to know the status of each.

- `myapps.mydomain.com`:

  - `ip-address-1:8080/up/up.html`
  - `ip-address-2:8080/up/up.html`

Now I am in the process of migrating the applications to OpenShift, and I have all application endpoints including `/up/up.html` exposed by OpenShift as `myapps.openshift.mydomain.com`.

For a period I would like to run the OpenShift apps in parallel with the legacy servers through the legacy load balancer - basically:

- `myapps.mydomain.com`:

  - `ip-address-1:8080/up/up.html`
  - `ip-address-2:8080/up/up.html`
  - `myapps.openshift.mydomain.com:80/up/up.html`

such that the load is distributed one third to each.

The guys managing the legacy load balancer claims that this cannot be done:-(

I myself dont know much about load balancers. I have been googling the subject and found articles about routing from "Edge Load Balancers" to Openshift, but I really dont know the right term for what I am trying to do.

I was hoping the load balancer could treat `myapps.openshift.mydomain.com` as just another blackbox - like the two legacy servers.

Can this be done?

And if so - what is the correct terminology for this concept - what is the proper name for what I am trying to do?

Comment: I would think as long as the invocations are stateless it should not matter. The only part I don't know is whether the LB can solve the myapps.openshift.mydomain.com as it can not resolved directly to an IP address :(

Comment: @wfink I believe the IP resolution is indeed the problem. I have worked around it for now with a small Spring Boot application based on https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet. It sits in between the LB and OpenShift and offers a static IP and port for the LB setup:)